# What thermal paste comes factory-applied with AMD Ryzen processors?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, thermal-paste

I've done my first PC Build and I was wondering what kind/brand thermal paste comes factory-applied with processors, I'm specially interested in the one that comes for **Ryzen 7 3700x** ([this box](https://tweakreviews.com/processor---cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3700x-8-core-zen-2)).

The reason I'am asking is because I thought I messed up the original thermal paste while installing, I've touched it mistake and a lot of it went to my fingers, and so I thought that it maybe wasn't enough paste to properly cool the processor. After that I tested temperature using [hwinfo64](https://www.hwinfo.com/).

Running [Intel Burn Test](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/intelburntest/) the temperature went to a maximum of **74°C at the maximum stress level**, now I know that temperature was excellent.

Then, I removed the original thermal paste and applied [Artic Silver 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0087X728K), and ran the test again... And so, temperature went to a **maximum of 84°C which is a lot hotter that it was before**,

I want my 74°C back :)

I've already done some research and couldn't find what kind of paste was the original one. Is there any similar commercial alternative?

Comment: It's most likely an unnamed OEM compound that's not available in retail.

Comment: I have seen comments that AMD uses Coolermaster paste.

Comment: You should look into how to apply thermal paste. Too much thermal paste will screw with performance too. But by default, OEM thermal pads will likely not perform as good as the better stuff such as arctic silver 5. So it is far more likely that you did something wrong while installing the cooling fan and thermal paste.

Comment: @LPChip Gamers Nexus [tested this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUWVVTY63hc) and apparently using too much thermal paste has negligible effect.

Comment: @gronostaj Linus Tech Tips made a video about it too and they actually had poor results when the thermal paste was applied poorly, as in... too much.

Comment: I had indeed too much thermal paste, I've removed it and then I reapplied by following most YouTubers recommendations, I thought that was it because tests showed a maximum of 76°C (which will be consistent with @harrymc theory of the Coolermaster paste), but then I got a spike of 86°C... I did the OEM thermal paste test after 5 days of using the PC and for Artic Silver 5 I did it just after a few minutes... I'll wait a few days to test again